# How to write a decorator to skip certain tests when a module is not imported?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I'm using [nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/testing.html) for testing. I know how to skip test, but I was wondering if there's an easy solution to write a decorator to skip tests, when some module is not imported.

Right now I try to import [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) and catch the `ImportError` if it isn't installed and set `mock = None`. At the start of tests that require mock I use `if not mock: raise SkipTest()` as the 1st line.

That works alright. I'm just wondering if it's also possible with a decorator?

### Update

I've been using [kindall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875744/11666) for some time, just to notice today, that *it still doesn't work right (at least not in **all** cases!*

It seems to work, when I use a test function, that is **not a generator** (contains no `yield` statement). Whenever I use the decorator on a test function that uses `yield` though, the test passes no matter if an `assert` fails in the yielded function.

Any ideas why this happens and how to prevent this kind of behavior?

Comment: Yes, `functools.wraps()` sets `__name__` and other attributes such as `__doc__`, so if you want to do it without `functools` that's the way.

Comment: Your update is an answer, if you want you can put it among them, but it doesn't belong in your question. If you'll do it your question will be more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
import functools

def requires_mock(test):

    @functools.wraps(test)
    def wrapper():
        if mock:
            return test()
        raise SkipTest

    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

The decorator should look like so:

```
def needsMock(fn):
    def wrapped():
        if mock is None: return

        fn()

    return wrapped
```

This makes the test pass when `mock` is `None`. You can also try to raise the `SkipTest()` but that might interfere with decorators.

Comment: No luck with this one: no errors but the test won't run. I guess ``nose`` couldn't find it because it's name didn't match the RegEx (``(?:^|[b_.-])[Tt]est)``).

Comment: The name of the decorator is irrelevant - nose runs it without noticing that it's there. Add a couple of `println` or run the code in a debugger to see where/why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by kindall's answer (which works) I tried to get it to work without `functools` again:

```
def requires_mock(test):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      if mock_not_available:
        raise SkipTest()
      else:
        return test(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.__name__ = test.__name__
    return wrapper
```

It seems to works too. The `__name__` thing is important so that [nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/testing.html) recognize the function and marks it on verbose test runs accordingly.

I hope I didn't miss anything? Loosing faith in you test is a sad thing :(